# Are rows in AMPscript the same as Arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

newbie to AMPscript and code in general. Currently learning JS.

If an Array is a variable that can hold multiple values at a time is that the same as a row in a DE/AMPscript? E.g Contacts can include name, address, age etc thats the same as an array right.

Answer (score 4):

An array is a list of ordered, unnamed elements. An object, also commonly called a Map, is a collection of named, unordered elements. So, a variable that has FirstName, LastName, and Email would be an object, while a variable that has the values "apple", "pear" and "orange," in that order, would be an array. A row in a Data Extension would be an object, while a list of Data Extensions would be an array.